# Searching for an algorithm with $\Theta(n2^n)$ time complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I am searching for an algorithm with a time complexity of $\Theta(n2^n)$ time complexity.
I am aware, that e.g. the Fibonacci sequence has a time complexity of $\Theta(2^n)$.

My plan was to add a loop in the implementation, so that before you go into recursion, you are going
to count from 1 to $n$. My question is, whether my plan is successful or if I made any mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want any algorithm with running time $\Theta(n 2^n)$ you can trivially compute $\ell = n 2^n$ from the input size $n$ and then have a loop of no-ops (or any constant number of "useless" elementary operations) iterate $\ell$ times.

If you are looking for a "reasonable" algorithm for a "well-known" problem with that time complexity, you can look for example at the brute-force solution for the subset-sum problem.
Given an input collection of $n$ non-negative integers $X=\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$ and $T \in \mathbb{N}$ the problem asks to decide whether there exists a subset $S$ of $X$ for which $\sum_{x_i \in S} x_i = T$.

A trivial brute-force algorithm for this problem looks at $2^n$ possible binary vectors $v_1, v_2, \dots \in \{0,1\}^n$ of length $n$, where each vector $v_i$ represents a subset of $X$. For each $v_i$ we explicitly check, in $\Theta(n)$ time, whether $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \cdot v_i = T$.
After all vectors have been examined, return "yes" if one such vector was found and "no" otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm with running time $O(n \cdot 2^n)$:

```python
def n2n(n):
    for i in range(n * 2**n):
        pass
```

You can test it with

```
from timeit import timeit
for i in range(20): 
    print(i,'\t', round(timeit(lambda : n2n(i), number=1000), 2))
```

which give running times (approximately)

```
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    0.0
5    0.0
6    0.01
7    0.02
8    0.04
9    0.09
10   0.23
11   0.48
12   0.97
13   1.91
14   4.03
15   8.58
16   18.17
17   49.32
18   83.48
19   171.05
```